# Having a bash script run at startup and display the results when I log in

Tags: ubuntu, startup

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and I want to be able to run a command like top so when I login it is running in a window.

I been trying many things for a while now and can't seem to get it to work

I added entries in the control panel under start up programs, but that didn't seem to work. I tried both having a script run, and actually typing the command, but neither was successful.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/63407/where-are-startup-commands-stored

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the "Startup Applications Preferences" window of the Ubuntu "Control Center", you need to do the following:

- Click "Add"

This will open an "Add Startup Program" window with three input fields.

You can fill in a name and a comment, they speak for themselves. The command field is the important one. You could write this:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e top
```

This line of text will be executed after X has started and right about when you see the "Ubuntu desktop" appearing. It will start a `gnome-terminal` and in it exectute the `top` command. The `-e` option causes this, because it stands for "execute the argument of this option inside the terminal".

If you like, you can also change the size and position of the terminal window. For that you use the `--geometry` option of the `gnome-terminal` command to specify this behavior.

See the `man` page (manual) of `gnome-terminal` for more details:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/gnome-terminal.1.html

Or a nice introduction here:
http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/

Answer (score 2):

You may need to delay the execution of the script until X is properly up and running; something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
( sleep 5 && exec xterm -e top ) &
```

Make this executable and add it to your autostart applications.

You can experiment with reducing the amount of `sleep` to suit what you need.